# Unable to run Office with same product key

Tags: macos, ms-office, license

I'd bought MS Office which was allowed to use on 3 Mac OSX with same product key. It was/is working fine when I'd installed it on 1st Macbook Pro. When I'd installed it on my iMac then MS Word, PowerPoint and Excel are working fine with same product key but MS Office is not working and getting alert for buy it.

[image]

[image]

Is there anything I am doing incorrect?

Comment: The 'O' icon is not Office- it's Outlook, their email client. Office includes Word, PowerPoint, Excel, and yes, Outlook. Home and Student family pack licenses do not include Outlook. Which kind do you have?

Comment: That is my company provide me. They got it free while purchasing iMac.

Comment: According to this http://www.microsoft.com/mac/buy you can't purchase Home and Business in a Family Pack; so you must have Home and Student if you claim it can be used on 3 Macs. Are you certain that the MacBook Pro has the same product key and is not running on a trial period for Outlook?

Comment: I agree with you, question was all Microsoft Office products are working fine then why not Outlook?

Comment: You should call the Microsoft customer support telephone number in your country and ask them to explain the situation and solve the problem. That is why they are there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is during install the installer pre installed all of the office apps, but your serial does not "unlock" Outlook which is used only in the business edition.

The only way to fix this is to pay for the upgrade through mactopia.com or calling microsoft, or to remove outlook.

Answer (score 0):

### Activate by phone

I encountered a similar problem in Office 2007 for Windows.

Even though I had uninstalled MS Office from another workstation, I was not allowed to use the same licence on a fresh install of Windows 7 Professional.

**I ended up calling Microsoft support via telephone. They then activated my licence without much hassle.**

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2391941 for more information on how to activate your licence by phone.

Also see this question on **[answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macstart/bought-new-mac-and-want-to-transfer-my-mac-office/2c7535ec-0cc5-44ef-a210-a2b787a07331?msgId=257dbe7a-8df9-470f-bd2d-cb882b29cd51)**.

Comment: But question is that, other product of Microsoft are working like MS Word, PowerPoint and Excel are working fine. Why there is issue with MS Office only? If there will be issue of Product Key then none will run.

Comment: @Machine Good point. I know via my firewall that *each* application of MS Office connects with registration servers of Microsoft. This may be related to the problem.

Comment: If *each* application of MS OFfice is connected through server of Microsoft then none should work, why is the issue with Office only.Now what next? Should I email them or what?

Comment: @Machine Maybe only Office completed the registration on the previous install (e.g. other applications weren't opened)? I don't know. Anyway, I wish you good luck in getting a useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for giving your precious time.Anyway, I am having iMail and Thunderbird both are configured. I want Office too for configuring my other email.Is there any other way of configuring two emails with iMail or Thunderbird?

Comment: @Machine You can setup multiple accounts of different providers in Mail, Thunderbird and MS Office. But I'd clearly recommend Mail from Apple as it's the easiest to use without loosing much functionality in comparison to the other two clients.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4272/discussion-between-machine-and-gentmatt)

Answer (score 0):

I installed MS Office:Mac 2011 (for university students) on my Mini and my MacBook. Each installation has a different product key - the last 3 digits are different. The installation allows for one primary and one portable computer for the same user.